# how to use mongoDB with visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I have installed MongoDB and downloaded MongoDB Csharp drivers, but when I am trying to connect to db it's not connecting. I have debug application and when it trying to create client it's showing message that "There is no source code available for the current location."
Please see attached screen shot for your reference.
and as far as I understood it's looking for MongoDB.Driver.dll but it's already there in my reference and in my using statement.
Look forward to hear from you guys soon.
thank you.[image]